# unable to filter table records using angular js in rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, angularjs, user-interface

I have a table named downloads which have some records in it.and i stored all records(in controller)

```
@records = Download.all
```

in view

```
<div ng-app>
<div ng-controller = "RecordCtrl">
  <input placeholder = "Enter fund name", ng-model="search">
    <div ng-repeat="record in records | filter:{fund: search}">
      <h2>{{record.fund}}</h2>
      <p>{{record.rating}}</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

i want to filter the records based on entering fund details.
i am new to angularjs is there anything has to be added anywhere.i tried it but neither get any results nor any error.

Comment: can you post your controller, angulars services and controller etc?

Comment: i didnt add anything in controller.

Comment: did you go through any angular tutorial?

Comment: ya...i gone through..http://spin.atomicobject.com/2013/11/22/pass-rails-data-angularjs/   ..and didnt get..then i found a thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19848283/angularjs-filter-in-rails

Comment: Do you want to search on the fund only?

Comment: @Sabyasachi Ghosh..ya...the search can be by any attribute..

Comment: Please check the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14733136/ng-repeat-filter-by-single-field

Comment: do i need to add anything in controller or any otherfiles...?

Comment: I guess no..........